# What is being "rendered" when comparing SSR vs CSR

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have read multiple articles trying to explain server-side rendering vs client-side rendering and I simply cannot seem to get a grasp of the concept. To me, when someone says "render" something, I think of the computer parsing the HTML file and presenting this to the computer screen, therefore the idea of server-side rendering makes no sense to me at first, as the idea would be for the server to parse and present it on it's own monitor.

I have seen articles mention that SSR is better for SEO, but my additional confusion comes from the fact that Create React App is a SPA, meaning to be a SPA it must load the entire page at once, and not make requests to the server when changing pages. Should this mean that since the page is loaded all at once that it is SEO friendly?

My question is, could somebody please explain what the key differences are between CSR (React app) vs SSR (Next.js) and what is meant by "rendering" and "compiling" in this context.

Comment: As you said, only the browser can parse the markup. But rendering is the process of displaying (csr) or sending (ssr) the HTML based on the client's request. It'll be easier to understand ssr if you know how php works.

Comment: SSR just means that the page's HTML is pre-generated on the server, and then sent to the client. As opposed to CSR where the page's HTML is generated on the client. The rendering always happens on the client in both scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

> server-side rendering makes no sense to me at first, as the idea would
> be for the server to parse and present it on it's own monitor.

Correct. "Rendering" is being misused here (in fact programmers seem to misuse pretty much every single word they use, even [the ones they themselves invent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29648972/14266931)).

CS"R" means that the HTML *code* is *constructed* on the client's browser by executing some JavaScript code. SS"R" means that that is done on the server (in whatever languange the server uses), which then sends the fully finished HTML code to the client.

*Proper* rendering (HTML to pixels in the screen) always happens client-side.

> to be a SPA it must load the entire page at once, and not make
> requests to the server when changing pages

Correct, however you can can hybrids. You can have your "S"PA load with some limited initial code, and each time the user navigates to an area that's "far away" and/or "heavy", you make a request to get the extra code to load it in (JS for CSR, or the HTML for SSR). Not necessarily an entire page, just a component.